# Add A Default Phone Number To Magento Order:

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, sales-order, paypal-express

Sometimes when I get an order from PayPal Express the customer Phone Number is always missing?

And this only happens when a customer uses the Guest Checkout Option.

I have tried changing the settings on PayPal but still no luck.

Is there a way to add a default Phone Number to an Order in Magento? See attached image.

I know I can use Event Observer to accomplish this task, but I don't know the right one to use in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have a phone number (required) field on the checkout even its guest checkout. So the customer can submit their phone number as well.

Event/Observer method:

`app/code/core/company/module/etc/config.xml`

```
<global>
        <models>
            <company_module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </company_module>
            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <add_phone_paypal_orders>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>company_module/observer</class>
                            <method>addPhonePaypalOrders</method>
                        </add_phone_paypal_orders>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>
        </models>
    </global>
```

`app/code/core/company/module/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Model_Observer
{
public function addPhonePaypalOrders($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $telephone = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();

        if(!$telephone)
        {
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setTelephone(123456789);
            try
            {
                $order->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do but that option is not there when they check out using the PayPal link on the http://www.domainname.com/checkout/cart/ .

Comment: check my edit. Give it a try